# How to specify null foreign key in symfony doctrine fixture

Tags: symfony1, null, fixtures

Here is a Doctrine schema:

```
Device:
  columns:
    name:           { type: string(60), }
    os_version_id:  { type: int(11), notnull: false }
  relations:
    OsVersion:
      foreignAlias: Devices

OsVersion:
  columns:
    version: { type: string(60), fixed: false, notnull: true }
```

Here is a fixture:

```
OSV_ABCD:
  version: ABCD

OSV_DEFG:
  version: DEFG

Device:
  Device_1:
    name: 'My device'
    OsVersion: null
```

When loading this fixture I get this:

```
Invalid row key specified: (os_version) , referred to in (device) Device_1
```

If I change `OsVersion: null` to `OsVersion: OSV_ABCD` it loads without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omitting the foreign key row entirely worked:

```
Device:
  Device_1:
    name: 'My device'
```